# install pip package with nexus3 repository and pypi proxy

Tags: python, proxy, repository, pip, nexus-5

I install nexus3(Nexus Repository 3.16.1-02) repository and create pypi repository.
[pypi repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgOOe.png)

and in my machine(centos 7) create repo file.

```
[Nexus_PYPI]
name= PYPI
baseurl= http://192.168.190.138:8081/repository/pypi-2/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When update yum repolist with command `yum repolist` get this error.
`http://192.168.190.138:8081/repository/pypi-2/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`

and when I want to install package pip, I can't and get this error.

```
[root@zk-kafka2 ~]# pip install kafka-utils
Collecting kafka-utils
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found',))': /simple/kafka-utils/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found',))': /simple/kafka-utils/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found',))': /simple/kafka-utils/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found',))': /simple/kafka-utils/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 404 Not Found',))': /simple/kafka-utils/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kafka-utils (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for kafka-utils
```

how can I use pypi repository proxy in nexus in install pip pakages?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use pip and PyPI on your machine, you'll need to configure a pip.conf not a create repo file.  See https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools specifically "Download, search and install packages using pip" subsection.

PyPI has its own metadata and does not use the one detailed so the errors returning (404) are 'correct'.